# mount.cifs syntax for read/write mount for non-root user

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, cifs

When I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 it also upgraded cifs.  In Ubuntu 12.x a network mount script I had would nicely mount a Windows network share as read/write.  My attempts at updating it to work with the new cifs have failed, see syntax attempted below which results in a read-only mount for my non-root account.  Note that even after making mount path 777/user:user the following results in the mount path changing to 755/root:root.

`sudo /sbin/mount.cifs $SHAREPOINT $MOUNTPOINT -o username=$user dom=$domain forceuid=$user forcegid=$user dynperm file_mode=777 dir_mode=777`

Comment: shouldnt there be commas instead of spaces between your various options?

Answer (score 3):

You want to pass `uid=user` as a mount option.  My `/etc/fstab` contains something like

```
//server/share  /home/user/win/H  cifs  uid=user,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```